# Subquery or two joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables:

```
tbl_trans
trans_id volume
a        10
b        20
c        30

tbl_primary_id
trans_id  primary_id
a         QQQ
b         b
c         RRR

tbl_name
trans_id   name
a          Billy
QQQ        Tom
b          Lizzy
RRR        Peter
```

I need to join the `name` column from `tbl_name` to `tbl_trans`.  A straight inner join won't work because I need `primary_id` as an intermediary to return this:

```
trans_id  tbl_name.trans_id volume  name
a         QQQ               10      Tom
a         QQQ               10      Billy
b         b                 20      Lizzy 
c         RRR               30      Peter
```

What's the best way to do this?  I was using a subquery but wasn't sure if there was a more direct statement.

(Side note:  None of this is my schema.  I can't modify the design in any way, unfortunately.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just 2 joins

```
select tt.trans_id, tn.trans_id, tt.volume, tn.name
from tbl_trans tt
inner join tbl_primary_id tti on tti.trans_id = tt.trans_id
inner join tbl_name tn on tn.trans_id = tti.primary_id
```

by the way, your column naming is a little bit weird : `primary_id` in `tbl_primary_id` is related with `trans_id` in `tbl_name`

oh, seems I missed something :

```
select tt.trans_id as tid, tti.primary_id as tid2, tt.volume, tn.name
from tbl_trans tt
inner join tbl_primary_id tti on tti.trans_id = tt.trans_id
inner join tbl_name tn on tn.trans_id = tti.primary_id or tn.trans_id = tti.trans_id
```

see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/470e3/6)

Comment: Are you sure this will work?  Wont the inner join not work if there is no primary_id to match a trans_id (even if there is a trans_id in the name table)?

Comment: @JeffreyKramer well, it's not really clear. Second answer (and sqlfiddle) should give you the desired result with your sample data...

Comment: Thanks, I never realized you could use an OR like that.  That's very good to know.